# Does a vector space need to be closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

What part of the definition of a vector space (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition)) requires it to be **closed** under addition and multiplication by a scalar in the field? I would understand if we defined a vector space as a group of vectors rather then a set but we don't, also non of the axioms require this to be a condition?

Comment: It's part of the definition, not the axioms. However, I might argue that the distributive axiom argues this...

Either way, you certainly can think of a vector space as a group under addition. In fact, any group is simply a set that satisfies part, but not all, of these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Wikipedia definition is tacitly noting that your set is (a) a group under addition, since the operation is defined to give $v + w \in V$ if $v$ and $w$ are in $V$, and the associativity, identity and inverse conditions give you a group. Also (b), the action of the field $F$ on $V$ is closed again by definition (since if $\alpha \in F$ and $v \in V$, we have $\alpha v \in V$.)

An equivalent—and possibly clearer—definition of vector space would foreground that the space is a group under addition and is closed under the action of the field.

Answer (score 3):

Because, addition and multiplication (by a scalar) operations are functions from $V \times V$ to $V$ and $K \times V$ to $V$, respectively.

Comment: I expanded your answer slightly. I think it is completely to the point, but was not easy to understand.